# Angular 4 : fill a complex model with a json HttpClient response

Tags: json, angular, angular-httpclient, angular-observable

I am trying to fill a model with the response of an API call using the new `HttpClientModule`. However, the attributes of the model aren't "json types" but complexe types.

Do you have any idea how can my `getById` and `getAll` method of `ReferenceService` return an `Observable` that match a real `Reference` object instead of just a json object ?

Here is an example of what i would like to do.

Thanks !

```
class Reference {
    id: number;
    title : string;
    type : Type;
    date : Date;
    tags : Array<Tag>;
    constructor(id : number = null, title : string = '', type : Type = new Type(), date : Date = new Date(), tags : Array<Tag> = []) {}
    display() {
        console.log(this.title);
        this.type.display();
    }
}

class Type {
    id: number;
    name : string;
    constructor(id : number = null, name : string = '') {}
    display() { console.log(this.name); }
}

class Tag {
    id: number;
    name : string;
    constructor(id : number = null, name : string = '') {}
}

@Injectable()
class ReferenceService {
    constructor(private http : HttpClient) {}
    getById(id: number) {
        return this.http.get<Reference>('/api/reference/'+id);
    }
    getAll() {
        return this.http.get<Array<Reference>>('/api/references');
    }
}

@Component({
    providers: [ReferenceService]
})
class ReferenceComponent implements OnInit {
    model: Reference;
    constructor(private referenceService : ReferenceService) {}
    ngOnInit() {
        this.referenceService
            .getById(42)    // hard coded for testing
            .subscribe( (data : Reference) => {
                this.model = data;
                console.log(this.model.display());
            });
    }
}
```

`

Comment: You have to provide the code to do that. The httpclient will return only json so you have to map that result back to your class or extend the returned class and add methods to it by changing the prototype. Either way there is nothing out of the box that will do it for you.